# Fix $x\in {[0,1)}$ . Is $f(n) = n(x^{1/n} -1)$ decreasing as a function of $n$?

Tags: calculus

Fix $x\in {[0,1)}$. Is $f(n) =  n(x^{1/n} -1)$ decreasing as a function of $n$?

I don't know why I'm getting stuck on this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how the derivative is related to the growth of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$f(n) = - \int_x^1 t^{1/n - 1} \, dt.$$ What happens to $t^{1/n - 1}$ as $n$ increases?

Comment: Solid way forward!  You beat me to this one so I went brute force.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be the function given by

$$g(x,y)=y(x^{1/y}-1)$$

Then, for fixed $x\in(0,1)$, and $y\ge 1$ we have

$$\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}=(x^{1/y}-1)\left(1-\frac{\log x}{y^2}\right)$$

Inasmuch as $x^{1/y}-1<0$ and $1-\frac{\log x}{y^2}>0$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and $y\ge 1$ we have $\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}<0$.  Therefore, $g$ is a decreasing function of $y$ in the domain of interest.  And we are done!

Answer (score 0):

With a change of variable, it is enough to prove that $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ is an increasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

However, that is trivial, since:
$$ \frac{e^x-1}{x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!} $$
is a convergent sum of positive increasing functions on $\mathbb{R}^+$.